# Why I get error group by result of subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to find the number of trace records which has same telephone,project_id,create_time,trace_content

But this sql:

```sql
select count(1) from trace WHERE  DATE(create_time)="2020-01-16" AND 
  id not in (
     select id from trace WHERE DATE(create_time)="2020-01-16"  
     GROUP BY telephone,project_id,create_time,trace_content
);
```

returns wrong result.
If I use:

```sql
select count(1) from trace WHERE  DATE(create_time)="2020-01-16" AND 
    id not in (
               select id FROM (
                      select id from trace WHERE DATE(create_time)="2020-01-16"  
                      GROUP BY telephone,project_id,create_time,trace_content
              ) a
);
```

returns correct result.
Mysql version is 5.6.26
Could anyone tell me the reason？

For example the table contains these data:

1. id = 1, project_id = 1, telephone = 1, trace_contest = test, creatime = 2020-01-16 18:27:46
2. id = 2, project_id = 1, telephone = 1, trace_contest = test, creatime = 2020-01-16 18:27:46
3. id = 3, project_id = 2, telephone = 2, trace_contest = test1, creatime = 2020-01-16 18:22:27

fisrt sql return 0, second sql return 1

Comment: Your `SELECT id ... GROUP BY ...` subquery returns random `id`s - one of all possible for each group. The fact that 2nd query returns "correct result" is random too.

Comment: @Akina Maybe it's not the reason subquery returns random id。If I use EXPLAIN command , the first sql  shows subquery  only using where without using filesort and  using temporary. But the second sql shows subquery using where ，using filesort and using temporary

Comment: @user12730122: it is unclear what you want to do, but likely, your query can be rewritten. Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Different plans == different random values. And nevertheless your "correct result" is random, and tomorrow it can become wrong.

Comment: @GMB I added the sample data  and results , I want the first sql return 1

Comment: @Akina Actually i don't care whether id is random. I only want to find the number of trace records which has same telephone,project_id,create_time and trace_content

Comment: Both queries are wrong. Both queries gives wrong results. But today the second result randomly occures to be identical to the correct result.

Comment: @Akina Actually I don't set sql mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, and it seems that in this mode, my group by sql returns the firstly searched data

Comment: *my group by sql returns the firstly searched data* Not searched. Scanned. Without filesort this is in most cases first posession in primary (clustered) index.

Comment: @Akina Id is primary key， and i think whether result is random is not important, i only want to know the number , not which record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your queries are actually wrong: your are selecting `id` but it is not not part of the `group by` clause, so you basically get a random value out of the group. In most RDBMS (and in non-ancient versions of MySQL), this would generate a syntax error.

I understand that you want to count how many `(telephone, project_id, create_time, trace_content)` occur more than once in the table.

You can use two levels of aggregation for this:

```
select count(*) cnt_duplicates
from (
    select 1
    from mytable
    where create_time >= '2020-01-16' and create_time < '2020-01-17'
    group by telephone, project_id, create_time, trace_content
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```

The inner query groups records and filters on those that occur more than one. The outer query counts how many records were returned by the inner query.

Note that I rewrote your condition on the date so it can take advantage of an index on `create_time`, if any.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want to know why first sql returns wrong result

Comment: Actually I don't set sql mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

Comment: and it seems that in this mode, my group by sql returns the firstly searched data

Comment: @user12730122: it returns a *random* record...In other words there is no guarantee that two different executions of the query will produce the same result.

Comment: Id is primary key，and i think whether id is random is not important, i only want to know the number 。